# How to hover on mobile device

Tags: html, css, mobile, hover

How can I implement an alternative for the hover feature on mobile devices such as a smartphone?  I have an image that has spots and once hovered over on desktop the message shows, but what can I use to show the messages on a smartphone?

I tried .hotspot:active but it never worked, unless I put it in the wrong place or I am doing something wrong.

```
.hotspot::before{
content:attr(text);
width: max-content;
position: absolute;
background-color: rgb(189, 189, 189);
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
width: 12em;
height:3em;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
top: 30px;

padding: 8px 20px;
font-size: 18px;
border-radius: 3px;
display: none;

}

.hotspot::after{
content: "";
border-color: transparent transparent black;
border-width: 0px 8px 6px;
border-style: solid;
position: absolute;
top:24px;
left:50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
display: none;

}


.hotspot:hover::before,
.hotspot::after{
 display: block;
 }
```

Comment: There is no `hover` on mobile devices, there is no logic to have. On mobile devices what is `hover` on desktop becomes on touch.

Comment: some people say :active or :focus works but I haven't managed to get them to work..